# Elasticsearch: Search Template via Java client?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

As the [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/search.html#java-search-template) describe, we can use a search template to send request to elasticsearch server by java API:

```
@Test
public void testTemplateQuery2() {
    Map<String, Object> template_params = new HashMap<>();
    template_params.put("query_string", "aaa bbb");
    StreamInput in;
    SearchRequestBuilder builder = client.prepareSearch()
            .setTemplateName("template_gender")
            .setTemplateType(ScriptService.ScriptType.FILE)
            .setTemplateParams(template_params);
    SearchResponse searchResponse = builder.get();
    System.out.println(searchResponse);
}
```

In this way I should create a file in **elasticsearch server** (/opt/elasticsearch-1.5.2/config/scripts/template_gender.mustache):

```
{
   "size" : 1,
   "_source" : ["timestamp"],
   "query": {
       "match": {
           "field1": "{{query_string}}"
       }
   }
}
```

However I want to configure this in my java side and I tried this :

```
   @Test
public void testTemplateQuery3() {
    Map<String, Object> template_params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    template_params.put("query_string", "aaa");
    SearchRequestBuilder builder = client.prepareSearch().setTimeout(TimeValue.timeValueMinutes(5))
            .setTemplateType(ScriptService.ScriptType.INLINE)
            .setTemplateSource("{'template' : {'size' : 1, '_source' : ['timestamp','field1'], 'query': { 'match': { 'field1': '{{query_string}}'}}}}".replace('\'', '"'))
            .setTemplateParams(template_params);

    SearchResponse searchResponse = builder.get();
    System.out.println(searchResponse);
}
```

But the query is parsed as below in server:

```
{"size":1,"_source":["timestamp","field1"],"query":{"match":{"field1":""}}}
```

the "query_string" are parsed as empty string "" ,why?

Comment: I would first recommend you to install marvel and try running your query; If that succeed then you are good to go for putting the same in programming; If not, then I would suggest to first correct the query.

Comment: the query works in curl